# How to debug grpc call?

Tags: grpc

I'm trying to figure out why my [grpc](http://grpc.io) call isn't working, but I can't figure out how to turn on debugging, so I can see the data that's being sent and received over the grpc connection.

How do you turn on debugging for grpc calls?

Comment: If your talking about web, grpc web plugin 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grpc-web-developer-tools/kanmilmfkjnoladbbamlclhccicldjaj could help you, make sure to read the doc as you need to enable the plugin for your clients in web.

Answer (score 59):

You can set the `GRPC_TRACE` environment variable to `all` to have grpc dump a whole bunch of data about what the connection is doing:

```
export GRPC_TRACE=all
```

**edit from comment**: apparently you also need to set:

```
export GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG
```

Comment: I tried this and didn't see anything in the console. Was there something else you did in your application to get the output?

Comment: Looks like only "C core based implementations" support these environment variables (for example Go is not one of them). For grpc-go, see `EnableGRPCTracing`. https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/trace#pkg-variables

Comment: It seems we can also set:
export GRPC_TRACE=list_tracers
Look here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/core/lib/debug/trace.cc#L42

Comment: Still doesn't work for me in python 3.5, Ubuntu 18.04 - I see no output :(

Comment: `GRPC_TRACE` doesn't work with `grpcurl`. I thought these core library variables would work with any gRPC program.

Answer (score 15):

In Golang, you need to set the [`GODEBUG` environment variable](https://godoc.org/net/http) to see HTTP2 traces, i.e. headers set by gRPC:

```
GODEBUG=http2debug=1   # enable verbose HTTP/2 debug logs
GODEBUG=http2debug=2   # ... even more verbose, with frame dumps
```

The output will then be sent to stdout. here's an example:

```
{"level":"info","msg":"2017/06/11 08:52:20 http2: Framer 0xc42009c0e0: wrote SETTINGS len=0","time":"2017-06-11T08:52:20Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"2017/06/11 08:52:20 http2: Framer 0xc42009c0e0: wrote WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=983025","time":"2017-06-11T08:52:20Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"2017/06/11 08:52:20 http2: Framer 0xc42009c0e0: read SETTINGS len=18, settings: ENABLE_PUSH=0, MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS=0, INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE=1048576","time":"2017-06-11T08:52:20Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"2017/06/11 08:52:20 http2: Framer 0xc42009c0e0: read WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=983041","time":"2017-06-11T08:52:20Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"2017/06/11 08:52:20 http2: Framer 0xc42009c0e0: wrote SETTINGS flags=ACK len=0","time":"2017-06-11T08:52:20Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"2017/06/11 08:52:20 http2: Framer 0xc42009c0e0: read SETTINGS flags=ACK len=0","time":"2017-06-11T08:52:20Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"2017/06/11 08:52:20 http2: Framer 0xc42009c0e0: read HEADERS flags=END_HEADERS|PRIORITY stream=3 len=249","time":"2017-06-11T08:52:20Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"2017/06/11 08:52:20 http2: decoded hpack field header field \":authority\" = \"\"","time":"2017-06-11T08:52:20Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"2017/06/11 08:52:20 http2: decoded hpack field header field \":path\" = \"/internal.push.v1.UnifiedDevicePush/SendMessage\"","time":"2017-06-11T08:52:20Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"2017/06/11 08:52:20 http2: decoded hpack field header field \":method\" = \"POST\"","time":"2017-06-11T08:52:20Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"2017/06/11 08:52:20 http2: decoded hpack field header field \":scheme\" = \"http\"","time":"2017-06-11T08:52:20Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"2017/06/11 08:52:20 http2: decoded hpack field header field \"content-type\" = \"application/grpc\"","time":"2017-06-11T08:52:20Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"2017/06/11 08:52:20 http2: decoded hpack field header field \"te\" = \"trailers\"","time":"2017-06-11T08:52:20Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"2017/06/11 08:52:20 http2: decoded hpack field header field \"user-agent\" = \"grpc-java-netty/1.0.3\"","time":"2017-06-11T08:52:20Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"2017/06/11 08:52:20 http2: decoded hpack field header field \"root-common.xirequestid-bin\" = \"ChIJzE6lBfCTCsYRoIIJujc92JY=\"","time":"2017-06-11T08:52:20Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"2017/06/11 08:52:20 http2: decoded hpack field header field \"te\" = \"trailers\"","time":"2017-06-11T08:52:20Z"}
```

Comment: @Dominik - thanks for the edit. I must've been high when I wrote this answer :/

Answer (score 10):

export GRPC_GO_LOG_VERBOSITY_LEVEL=99
export GRPC_GO_LOG_SEVERITY_LEVEL=info

Try this with latest grpc go version.

Answer (score 6):

From the [docs](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md)

> `GRPC_VERBOSITY` is used to set the minimum level of log messages printed by gRPC (supported values are `DEBUG`, `INFO`, and `ERROR`). If this environment variable is unset, only `ERROR` logs will be printed.

Also, check [`GRPC_TRACE`](https://grpc.io/search/?q=GRPC_TRACE)

There are 15+ grpc environment [variables](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md)

A note for Windows users, quoting from [docs](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md):

Known limitations: `GPRC_TRACE=tcp` is currently not implemented for Windows (you won't see any TCP traces).

Comment: Tried that, this is useless for "print request/response with message". I didn't find any usefull output. I think these flags are only for developers of the GRPC C library.

Comment: @juwens I doubt that these flags are only for the developers of the grpc c library, as the answer by OP has many upvotes which indicate that at least a few flags were useful to others.

Comment: Thanks. This is how the proper answer should look like - include those references.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Mediator](https://github.com/ButterCam/Mediator) Tool to debug and tracing gRPC calls.

It is a GUI tool just like the [charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/), but if you need to resolve the protobuf
message body, the gRPC server needs to support the [Server Reflection](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/server-reflection.md).

Answer (score 0):

There is another tool [grpcdebug](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/awesome-grpc)

> grpcdebug is a command line interface focusing on simplifying the debugging process of gRPC applications. grpcdebug fetches the internal states of the gRPC library from the application via gRPC protocol and provide a human-friendly UX to browse them. Currently, it supports Channelz/Health Checking/CSDS (aka. admin services). In other words, it can fetch statistics about how many RPCs has being sent or failed on a given gRPC channel, it can inspect address resolution results, it can dump the in-effective xDS configuration that directs the routing of RPCs.

Here are some samples

- Usage 1: Raw Channelz Output

For all Channelz commands, you can add --json to get the raw Channelz output.

```
grpcdebug localhost:50051 channelz channels --json
grpcdebug localhost:50051 channelz servers --json
```

- Usage 2: List Client Channels

grpcdebug localhost:50051 channelz channels

```
# Channel ID   Target            State     Calls(Started/Succeeded/Failed)   Created Time
# 7            localhost:10001   READY     5136/4631/505                     8 minutes ago
```

- Usage 3: List Servers

grpcdebug localhost:50051 channelz servers

```
# Server ID   Listen Addresses   Calls(Started/Succeeded/Failed)   Last Call Started
# 1           [:::10001]         2852/2530/322                     now
# 2           [:::50051]         29/28/0                           now
# 3           [:::50052]         4/4/0                             26 seconds ago
```