# How can I measure the response time with grpc_cli for a gRPC call?

Tags: performance, grpc

`curl` is able to measure the response time of a request, as illustrated by https://stackoverflow.com/a/22625150/1150462 . Can `grpc_cli` achieve this for gRPC calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.

The docs for [`grpc_cli`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/command_line_tool.md) and the other common tools ([`gRPCurl`](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl), [`ghz`](https://ghz.sh/docs/usage)) appear to not support this level of complexity.

I **suspect** this is a reflection of tool maturity.

It may be worth, filing an issue against a tool to see whether such timing is planned.

gRPC language runtimes support quite [extensive debugging|tracing through environment variables](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md) and,I think the output does include some timings though you would then need to parse the output or program the runtime. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44482155/609290) answer.

A friend blogged about using [gRPC with curl](https://blog.salrashid.dev/articles/2017/grpc_curl/). It's a "the hard way" solution but it would be interesting to learn with `curl`'s [`write-out`](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/verbose/writeout) works then too.